# Are there curves of genus 2 and higher over number fields with everywhere good reduction?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

a theorem of Fontaine states that there are no curves of genus $\geq 1$ over $\mathbb Q$ with everywhere good reduction.

For curves of genus one over number fields, this is not true. There are number fields where one can construct elliptic curves with everywhere good reduction (e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0651).

But what if we go over to genus $\geq 2$ ? Is there a statement like

> There is no curve of genus $\geq 2$ over a number field with everywhere good reduction.

?

Kind regards,

reinbot

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139774/curves-with-good-reduction-everywhere

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/

Comment: Does the example on the top of page 4 [here](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/MasterSerra.pdf) answer your question?

Comment: Moreover, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139774/ tells you that for every genus $g$, there is a number field $K$ and a curve $X$ over $K$, such that $X$ has good reduction at all the places of $K$.

Comment: The link in the comment from  Dec 3, 2018 at 12:59 is now https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/masterserra.pdf, or see https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOHPk.png